# Whenever I switch languages OneNote/Windows mail loses focus

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote, windows-mail

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination in Windows 10 is set up to switch between languages. Whenever I press it in OneNote, the ribbon menu opens and the note I'm typing loses focus. I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return the focus to OneNote.

It happens on both of my Windows 10 computers. Other Office applications, including OneNote 2016 and Outlook, don't have this issue. This happens in OneNote for Windows 10 and Windows Mail program.

I've looked around and googled it, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: How about changing the shortcut key for switching language, such as Ctrl+Shift?

Comment: I'm not too old, but grumpy enough :) also, my less computer friendly family members and colleagues are using this PC too. And alt+shift is kind of standard key combination, as far as I know.

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows key + Space combo? That's Windows 10's modern language switcher.

Comment: @MoonRunestar basically it's the same(with nice pop-up), and it does not causes focus loss(So it helps). But it's not what I've tried to achieve.